# Angular JS: Making a table cell password type

Tags: angularjs, html, user-interface

I an using Angular JS and creating a table which is kind of property table that have username, password, filepath information. When the first col value is password then its corresponding second col should be treat like password field.

It is possible using Angular js.

Overall I want to make table's cell customize.

I am following the link sample

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">  
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "ProfileName", value: "MyProfile"},
                     {name: "UserName", value: "john"},
                     {name: "Password", value: "showBePasswordType"},
                     {name: "Other", value: "nothing"}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        enableCellSelection: true,
        enableRowSelection: false,
        enableCellEdit: true,
        columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true}, 
                     {field:'value', displayName:'Value', enableCellEdit: true}]
    };
});
```

Comment: Could you put it in a fiddle or a plunker ? I've got a hard time trying to imagine the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to have one cell of the table which has the same behavior as an input field with the type set to password?

```
<input type="password">
```

You could stick to the HTML input type identifiers, and check which type you are dealing with to print out the correct input in HTML.

```
<input ng-switch-when="text" type="text" id="{{elem.id}}" name="{{elem.id}}" class="{{elem.class}}">
<input ng-switch-when="password" type="password" id="{{elem.id}}" name="{{elem.id}}" class="{{elem.class}}">
<input ng-switch-when="email" type="email" id="{{elem.id}}" name="{{elem.id}}" class="{{elem.class}}">
```

Your question asks for a table, and since you have HTML5 set as a tag, I assume that you are using this. So then you could simply include the input fields in the table cells. (Note that this won't work in HTML4, since a form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr.

```
<form method="GET" id="my_form"></form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input ng-switch-when="password" type="password" id="{{elem.id}}" name="{{elem.id}}" class="{{elem.class}}">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know if I missed/misunderstood something.

Comment: Thanks Daan, I will try it and let you know. The older of row is not fixed, row having "password" can be at any index (row number). So I want to confirm by the first col value, if it is "Password" then next col should show as password type. and number of rows also vary.

Thanks once again for reply...

Comment: You are most welcome. If it is working out for you, please set it as the accepted answer. If you have further questions I'll be here ;)

Comment: Hi Daan, This is my sample program... http://plnkr.co/edit/DGQ8QDAxJaJ2js8t91A5?p=preview
Here you can see for Password as I make it green color, Now I want to show it in asterisk instead of showing actual password string.
I did tried with conditional statement in tejTemplate but it showing statement as string. Can I add control like <input type="password"> which field is password ?

Comment: Yes, the tejTemplate2 that you commented out actually works: http://plnkr.co/edit/haO3CWZp8vLR0xonSLKn?p=preview. You can see that only for the password input, it has been set to type="password". The problem you also had was that if enableCellEdit set to true, it will also automatically create an input on double click. I have solved this by setting enableCellEdit to false, and adding an input field as default in the switch

Comment: This however means that you are overwriting the functionality of ng-grid.